# Dialog is lagging on View inflation

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a `Dialog` with 14 `Spinner` . Only single `Adapter` is being set on Each Spinner .

Calling `.show()` on dialog it lags and shown after 5 or 6 seconds for the first time. Next time i just `hide()` and `show()` so its work perfectly.
Here is MCVE.

```
class HourDialog extends Dialog {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    setDateAdapter();
}

private void setDateAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter adapterDate = new ArrayAdapter<>(c, R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.spinner_item_tv, c.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours_arrays));
    monSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    tueSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    wedSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    thusSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    friSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    satSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    sunSpinnerFrom.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    monSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    tueSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    wedSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    thusSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    friSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    satSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
    sunSpinnerTo.setAdapter(adapterDate);
}
}
```

I think i should come up with a better UI/UX for getting input for hours except 14 spinners . But is there a possibility to resolve this issue ?  I am currently setting adapters in `onCreate()`. I also tried to set adapters in `onShowListener` but nothing changed.

I think a `DialogFragment` will give the same effect as its also a `Dialog`. Dialog Themed Activity can be a solution maybe but i have not checked it yet .

Comment: There is no heavy work . Just the UI stuff . Setting adapters to each `Spinner` . Have a look at code .

Comment: use profiler to check what is causing this lag

Comment: Setting adapters is causing lag . I have commented `setDateAdapter();` all goes smooth . With ` setDateAdapter();` its lagging too much 6 seconds approx.

Comment: so its simple isnt it, in `onCreate` use asynctask to set the adapters

Comment: How the hell i am going to set Adapter in `AsyncTask`? We can not touch view hierarchy from non Ui thread .

Comment: there is a method named `runOnUiThread()` bro

Comment: What the hell man ? DO you even understand what you talking about ? `runOnUiThread` will post the code again on UI . So its will change nothing . And FYI `runOnUiThread` is method of `Activity` not `Dialog` . And its also useless in this `Context`. Do not make assumptions if you do not know the solution.